# При чтении ответа из БД в ридере выпадает ошибка на NULL

Tags: c#, oracle

При чтении ответа из БД в ридере выпадает ошибка на `NULL`. Я начинающий еще программист. Можно ли как то проверить весь ридер за раз на проверку на `NULL`

```
var res = new SKURES { Header = new HEADER(), Orgs = new List<ORG>() };

using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.HasRows) 
    {
        // выводим названия столбцов
        Console.WriteLine("{0} \t{1} \t{2} \t{3} \t{4}", reader.GetName(0), reader.GetName(1), reader.GetName(2), reader.GetName(3), reader.GetName(4));

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var obj = new ORG();

            obj.NAME = reader.GetString(0);
            obj.REG_NUM = reader.GetString(1);
            obj.WRO = reader.GetInt32(2);
            obj.INN = reader.GetString(3);
            obj.KPP = reader.GetString(4);

            res.Orgs.Add(obj);
        }
        res.Header.RESULT = res.Orgs.Count();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен проверкой некоторых полей на NULL

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(7))
    obj.ZIP = reader.GetString(7);
```